# What priority order for MIME types (contain in accept header from request) consider by Jersey while selecting the appropriate restful endpoint

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, mime-types

Please refer to the below code snippet

@Path("/hello")

```
public class Hello {

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XHTML_XML)
  public String sayApplicationXhtmlXml() {
    System.out.println("Application XHTML XML IS ACCEPTED");  
    return "Hello Jersey";
  }


  @GET
  @Produces("*/*")
  public String sayAllMimeTypes() {
    System.out.println("All MIME TYPES IS ACCEPTED");
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello " + "</hello>";
  }
}
```

When I am sending request from firefox with header

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,asterisk/asterisk;q=0.8
```

which is default header of firefox.

output is

```
ALL MIME TYPES IS ACCEPTED
```

I think something wrong it.

As per my understanding, output should be

```
Application XHTML XML IS ACCEPTED
```

because `application/xhtml+xml` appears before `"asterisk/asterisk"` in `Accept` header (As per rule according to which if default value of q=1.0 for both of them so whoever appears first should be given higher priority)

Comment: I don't think this is an HTTP thing, it seems to be a Jersey thing. I just takes the first it finds that matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your request header, you specify that both `text/html` and `application/xhtml+xml` have equal quality factor (default to 1). They both have higher `q` value than the `*/*` wildcard type. However for Jersey, when two MIME types have equal `q` values, then it will choose the MIME type according to the order they appear. So in this case, `text/html` will be chosen and since your second method `sayAllMimeTypes()` produces any MIME types including `text/html`. Therefore the second method is invoked.

Comment: I just needed to clarify, you mean to say since second method have @produces(*/*) as mimetype, It signifies that it can produce any MIME types.Therefor Jersey selecting these one as these method can produce (text/html) as mimetype which is of highest priority in incoming Accept Header

Comment: That is correct. The second method matches the highest priority MIME type in the request header (text/html).

Comment: If while sending request we swap order of text/html and application/xhtml+xml in header then Which one of the resource will be invoked by Jersey?

Comment: Am sure you should have got the answer for your above question. But am testing my understanding here :) When you swapped the order, didn't you see the output from the first method i.e "Application XHTML XML IS ACCEPTED"?